# iPhone won't play audio file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, record

I am trying to make a recording app, so obviously i need to be able to record and play an audio file. It seems like it's working, no errors at all, but it won't work. I'm not sure that it's actually recording?

It should create the sound file itself, right? i don't have to put in a sound file to the project do i?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    playButton.enabled = NO;
    stopButton.enabled = NO;

    NSArray *dirPaths;
    NSString *docsDir;

    dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(
                                                   NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [docsDir
                               stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound.caf"];

    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];

    NSDictionary *recordSettings = [NSDictionary 
                                    dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:AVAudioQualityMin],
                                    AVEncoderAudioQualityKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt:16], 
                                    AVEncoderBitRateKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithInt: 2], 
                                    AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                    [NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0], 
                                    AVSampleRateKey,
                                    nil];

    NSError *error = nil;

    audioRecorder = [[AVAudioRecorder alloc]
                     initWithURL:soundFileURL
                     settings:recordSettings
                     error:&error];

    if (error)
    {
        NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    } else {
        [audioRecorder prepareToRecord];
    }

}

// Methods called by the start recording button, stop recording, and play.
-(void) recordAudio
{
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        playButton.enabled = NO;
        stopButton.enabled = YES;
        [audioRecorder record];
    }
}
-(void)stop
{
    stopButton.enabled = NO;
    playButton.enabled = YES;
    recordButton.enabled = YES;

    if (audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        [audioRecorder stop];
    } else if (audioPlayer.playing) {
        [audioPlayer stop];
    }
}
-(void) playAudio
{
    if (!audioRecorder.recording)
    {
        stopButton.enabled = YES;
        recordButton.enabled = NO;

        NSError *error;

        audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] 
                       initWithContentsOfURL:audioRecorder.url                                    
                       error:&error];

        audioPlayer.delegate = self;

        if (error)
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", 
                  [error localizedDescription]);
        else {
            [audioPlayer setVolume:1.0];
            [audioPlayer play];
        }
    }
}

// Delegate methods

-(void)audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    recordButton.enabled = YES;
    stopButton.enabled = NO;

    NSLog(@"did play");
}
-(void)audioPlayerDecodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioPlayer *)player 
                                error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Decode Error occurred");
}
-(void)audioRecorderDidFinishRecording:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
                          successfully:(BOOL)flag
{
    NSLog(@"did record");
}
-(void)audioRecorderEncodeErrorDidOccur:
(AVAudioRecorder *)recorder 
                                  error:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Encode Error occurred");
}
```

Thanks on advance. I'm very new to the whole recording thing and working with audio files and directories.

Comment: Did you just copy and paste from http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29

Comment: Yes i did - when learning new concepts, i tend to copy-paste some pre-defined stuff, get it working, mess around with it and see what happens, and THEN create my own from scratch - every man learns differently, this works for me - so i gotta get this working first :)

Comment: I was just asking, The one problem with that is if it doesn't work from the start you have no idea what's worong with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding AVAudioSession code as following..

```
NSError *error; 

AVAudioSession * audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];

[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];

[audioSession setActive:YES error: &error];
```